# How can I indent a selected block of text in Eclipse 3.5.2?

Tags: eclipse

I use TAB and Shift-Tab in Visual Studio to indent an entire selection. This does nothing in Eclipse, and I can't seem to find another way to do it.

Update: I wasn't really paying all that much attention to this initially and did not ask the question correctly.
I now realized that it is in XML files where TAB still does not indent a selection. I did not find a setting for this in the properties, so I assume it is not possible.

Comment: Even in the XML editor, you can use `Source -> Shift Left` and `Source -> Shift Right` (from the menus.)

Comment: Just as a note, more recent versions of eclipse support Tab and shift-Tab to indent and de-indent blocks of code

Answer (score 47, accepted):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> are the normal ways to do this in Eclipse, just like in Visual Studio.

In addition to the keyboard shortcuts, you can also do this from the Source menu. Source -> Shift Left, and Source -> Shift Right.

Have you checked to make sure tab/shift tabbing is working as you expect in other applications? Is there a stuck key on your keyboard preventing the shortcuts from working? Could another application be stealing the keyboard shortcuts? (as odd as that sounds...)

Also, try restarting Eclipse.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `Source -> Shift Left` and `Source -> Shift Right` - those even work in the XML editor!

Answer (score 6):

ctrl + i  ---> it is for making accurate indentation to a block of source code.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Window Menu -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing and make sure the `'Tab key adjusts the indentation of the current line' checkbox is ticked.

Comment: It was ticked. This actually works today, without me changing anything (other than restarting Eclipse, which is why I accepted Joshua's answer).